# Does adding code to filter to modify your images on the fly slow down the loading time?

Tags: javascript, css, filter, instagram, photo

I am working on a visual travel/lifestyle blog. I want all the images to have a uniform feel to them. Rather than hire a photographer to retouch the images, and rather than using a separate app to add photo filters to the images before they are uploaded, I thought maybe I can find a good filter script or canva code to add a cast or tone to the images as they load. Does adding code to photo filter your images on the fly slow down the loading time? Do you recommend any good filters or solutions?

Comment: This question seems like it is more related to your line of business than coding. I would suggest coming up with a specific example of your performance question and tagging it as being perf related

Answer (score 0):

Adding code to photo filter your images on the fly won't slow down "loading time", but will add some processing time before the user sees the image.

For a single image of reasonable size, this time won't even be noticeable, and probably wont be until you have a hundred of images.

So you might want to do some benchmarking to find an upper limit on the number of displayed images if you want the processing time to be bound.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. "won't even be noticeable" means like a millisecond, right? But I imagine that if a page has a multi-photo magazine-like layout, that is what you mean by the number of images? If the page is a scroll of ongoing blog additions, this could be problematic? I guess my question is, what constitutes a page when it comes to a blog format? So you suggest A/B testing kind of, right?

Also, do you recommend one brand or source for this kind of script than others?

Comment: Using webgl, yes, magnitude of millisecond. By number of images, i mean number of images that need to be processed at the same time. If images are loaded as the user scrolls, the whole process will probably be unnoticed by the user. Not knowing exactly what kind of filtering you want, i cannot recommend anything, you still can go the hard way : https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html !